# jquery calling multiple array in one textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this code here:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() { 
    $.getJSON("url/getuserdetails.php?callback=?",{username: localStorage.getItem("datausername")},function(data)
            {
            $("#txtname").val(data.fname);
            $("#txtemail").val(data.email);
            });
    }, 500);
    </script>
```

An I need to display the 3 column to the textbox with the id of txtname which I have this code in my php file

```
echo $_GET['callback']."(".json_encode(array("fname"=>$row['firstname'],"mname"=>$row['middlename'],"lname"=>$row['lastname'],"email"=>$row['email'],)).");";
```

I need to display the fname, mname, and lname in one textbox. I tried it like this but its not working.

```
$("#txtname").val(data.fname + " " + data.mname + " " + data.lname);
```

Can anyone please correct my code? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is coming in the `data` ?

Comment: oh I'm very sorry for this but my codes working properly it's only on my simulator. I'm very sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return this
    `echo json_encode(array("fname"=>$row['firstname'],"mname"=>$row['middlename'],"lname"=>$row['lastname'],"email"=>$row['email']));`

Comment: the OP expects JSONP as we can see `callback=?` in `"url/getuserdetails.php?callback=?"`. The `url` part could point to another domain

Comment: oh I'm very sorry for this but my codes working properly it's only on my simulator. I'm very sorry.